# SQL Update using Case results

Tags: sql, case

I need to update a value in file1 with the contents of a field in another file2 with a matching key, but only if a row is found in file2 that matches. Otherwise, update file1 field with a 'Q' literal. 
This works, but seems redundant, and takes too long? Suggestions?

```
update ZXU                                                 
set XUATTN =  case when (select count(*) from ZXK       
                         where XKUSER = 'TOMTEST') > 0 
                  then (select XKAUTH from ZXK         
                         where XKUSER = 'TOMTEST')     
                  else 'Q'                             
             end                                       
where XUUSER='TOMTEST'
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: There's probably a better way to write this, but the "how" will depend on which database platform you're using. `UPDATE` syntax varies widely by product. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE()`:

```
update ZXU
    set XUATTN = COALESCE( (select k.XKAUTH from ZXK k where k.XKUSER = ZHU.XUUSER), 'Q')
    where XUUSER = 'TOMTEST';
```

I will note that this (and your code) will generate an error if the subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. Much cleaner.